# bash script if statement not displaying true

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to get a quick script together to check a file system prior to running resize2fs.

```
#!/bin/bash
var2=$(dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/mylv | grep "Filesystem state:")
var1=test
echo $var1
echo $var2

if [ "$var2" = "Filesystem state: clean" ];
then
        echo "clean"
else
        echo "dirty"
fi
```

---

My results

```
Server1:~ # ./filesystest.sh
dumpe2fs 1.38 (30-Jun-2005)
test
Filesystem state: clean
dirty
```

---

It seems even though var2 is in fact "Filesystem state: clean" it still shows up false.

Comment: Do `echo "$var2"` (with quotes). Perhaps there are other characters in the output, not showing (e.g. double spaces).

Comment: try running w/ #!/bin/bash -x, it'll show you the results as they are run. This will also let you see var2, it's probably not what you think.

Comment: So I just tried echo "$var2" with this output. upbcreld03:~ # ./filesystest.sh
dumpe2fs 1.38 (30-Jun-2005)
test
Filesystem state: clean
Filesystem state:         clean
dirty

So it does look like var2 and "var2" were not the same.

Comment: @bashophil Actually, `=` (the POSIX-compliant syntax) is more correct than `==` (an extension added in bash only).

Comment: @bashophil Added the == to the script.

Comment: @james You shouldn't; bashophil gave you frankly wrong advice.

Comment: @james `echo "$var2"` doesn't display things in a way that visually distinguishes between tabs and spaces (for instance). You're actually better off with `set -x` or `printf '%q\n' "$var2"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have extra characters (maybe spaces) in `var2`.

Instead of saying:

```
if [ "$var2" = "Filesystem state: clean" ];
```

say:

```
if [[ "$var2" =~ "Filesystem state: clean" ]];
```

EDIT: In fact, your entire script can be written as:

```
dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/mylv | grep -q "Filesystem state: clean" && echo "clean" || echo "dirty"
```

Comment: I am looking at this prior to determining if an fsck should be performed prior to resiz2fs. If its clean I see no reason for the fsck, if it is dirty or "not clean" I would run the check.

Comment: Instead of `echo "dirty"` in the above command (see last line), mention your `fsck` command.  If the fs is dirty, then `fsck` would be performed else not.  The subsequent line can be for `resiz2fs`.

Comment: Using `foo && foo_was_true || foo_was_false` as if it were `if foo; then foo_was_true; else foo_was_false; fi` is a bad practice, because `foo_was_false` can be run if `foo` was true but `foo_was_true` failed. (In the case of an `echo`, think of the case where stdout is a closed FD).

Comment: @devnull

`code`echo ****** Checking File System Status ******
var2=$(dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/gwvg-gwlv | grep "Filesystem state:")
#var1=test
#echo $var1
#echo $var2
#echo "$var2"

if [[ "$var2" = "Filesystem state:         clean" ]];
then
        echo ****** Skipping FSCK ******
echo ****** Starting Resize filesystem NO FSCK ******
resize2fs -d 1 -f -p /dev/gwvg/mylv

else
        echo ****** Starting FSCK ******
e2fsck -f -v -y /dev/gwvg/mylv

fi

echo ****** Sending Email ******
mailx -s servername email@domain.org @ < resize_complete

echo ****** Mounting VOL1 ******
mount /VOL1

Comment: I agree with you in principle but if stdout is a closed FD, then chances are there would be *bigger* problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the varying output of dumpe2fs I think you should check it like this instead:

```
shopt -s extglob
if [[ $var2 == 'Filesystem state:'*([[:blank:]])'clean' ]]
```

Or with regex:

```
if [[ $var2 =~ 'Filesystem state:'[[:blank:]]*'clean' ]]
```

Also, you could apply the command directly with this:

```
if dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/mylv 2>&1 | grep -q "Filesystem state:[[:blank:]]*clean"
then
```

If you want to get the state of the filesystem, you can do this:

```
state=$(exec dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/mylv 2>&1 | sed -ne '/Filesystem state:/s/.*state:\s*//p')
```

Comment: When a file system is not clean , it is defined as "not clean" so *clean* would leave me in an always clean state. I modified the script .
    #!/bin/bash
    var2=$(dumpe2fs -h /dev/mapper/myvl | grep "Filesystem state:")
    var1=test
    echo $var1
    echo $var2
    echo "$var2"

    if [[ "$var2" = "Filesystem state:         clean" ]];
    then
        echo "clean"
    else
        echo "dirty"
    fi


Output : 

dumpe2fs 1.38 (30-Jun-2005)
test
Filesystem state: clean
Filesystem state:         clean
clean

Comment: @james I see. I made changes for it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this check:

```
if [ "$var2" = "Filesystem state: clean" ];
```

try this check:

```
if [[ "$var2" = *"Filesystem state: clean"* ]];
```

Comment: The only thing I would change about this would be using `=` rather than `==` even in the `[[ ]]` case; no point in picking up habits that can't be carried back to POSIX when they add no value.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Added == to the script.

Comment: @james pardon? `=` is more correct; `==` is (slightly) wrong (because it encourages habits that don't comply with POSIX).